# How to re-wrap phase image

Tags: python, phase, unwrap

I got several phase images ([-pi,pi]),and these images are interfeogram.
I succeed in wrapping unwrapping velocity image by following code

```
from skimage import exposure
image= exposure.rescale_intensity(image, out_range=(0,4*np.pi))
image_wrapped = np.angle(np.exp(1j * (image)))
```

I am tring to re-wrap the wrapping phase to different interval like [-2,2],[-1,1] ,and I tried to use

```
a=-2
phases = (image + a) % (2 * a) - a
```

Dose it make sense for rewrapping phase?